# How to find bi-grams which are separated by a window of N tokens?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I was trying to find a way to get all bigrams from a piece of text which are not necessarily consecutive words but are separated by N words in the text, using python. Although I have found many answers on how to find consecutive bigrams I have not found a clear answer regarding non-consecutive bi-grams.

I was using `sklearn` and `CountVectorizer`, as the code below, to find my bigrams, but I don't know if it is able to do this task.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#finding bigrams and their frequency
bigram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
X = bigram_vectorizer.fit_transform(["i love coding with python"])
print(bigram_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
bigram_frequency = X.toarray()
```

Which prints:

```
["i love", "love coding", "coding with", "with python"]
```

The expected result, having a piece of text `sentence= "i love coding with python"` should return something like:

```
[('i', 'love'), ('i', 'coding'), ('i', 'with'), ... ,('coding', 'with'), 
('coding', 'python'), ('with', 'python')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be solved with sklearn? To find the bigrams use this function:

```
 def nonConsBigram(text):
     x = text.split(' ')
     ret = []
     while len(x) > 1:
         current = x[0]
         for i in x[1:]:
             ret += [(current, i)]
         x = x[1:]
     return ret
```

Results in:

```
[('i', 'love'),
 ('i', 'coding'),
 ('i', 'with'),
 ('i', 'python'),
 ('love', 'coding'),
 ('love', 'with'),
 ('love', 'python'),
 ('coding', 'with'),
 ('coding', 'python'),
 ('with', 'python')]
```

Comment: No, there is no need to be solved in sklearn. This works absolutely fine. However, I also need to find the frequency of these bigrams in different groups of text and create an array of frequency vectors. Is it possible with this method please?
Thanks

Comment: @Steve well then you should edit your question to point that out. I am not quite sure what you want by frequency. you want to count them? Maybe provide an example